# User defined functions in zend

Tags: zend-framework

Where do i place the user defined functions in zend framework. These functions will used across the framework in many controls, views or models. Do i need to convert this to a utility class? Or i can just keep it as a set of functions and include it in index.php.

what is the best practice for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you would put your functions into a class in the library for the auto loader. Use the naming conventions for ZF to make life easier.
adjust your application.ini to add a namespace.

**Examples:**

```
//application.ini
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "My_"



 //this would equate to the folder My in the folder library
    /application
      /library
         /My

 //any class you built would be named My_Classname and be called in your app by Classname()
 <?php
  class My_Classname {
     public function myFunction() {
    }
  }

  //in your conrtoller for example you might call 

  public function indexAction()  {
   $class = new My_Classname();
   $class->myFunction();

   //or if you declared myFunction() static...
   $class = My_Classname::myFunction();
  }
```

Comment: Many Thanks for suggesting this idea. I just implemented it and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make it by following ZF directory structure:

Make Action Helpers for Controllers and View Helpers for Views :

In your library folder which is set in set_include_path:

```
create library/My/View/Helper/Common.php
```

Like below:

```
    class My_View_Helper_Common extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
    {
        public function common()
        {
          return $this; 
        }
        public function getCity($id)
        {
            $registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance();
            $DB = $registry['DB'];  

            $result = $DB->fetchPairs("select * from firm_dtl");

            return $result;
        }
 }
```

OR Call in View:

```
$this->common()->getCity($id);
```

Same process fro action helpers:

Make in  library/My/Action/Helper/Common.php